# java polymorphism creating object

Tags: java, polymorphism

I need to make a program that run process on text, audio and video files,

I create an interface class and three class that inherit it

```
public interface FileProcess{
    public void process();    
}

public class TextProcess implements FileProcess{ 
    public void process(){System.out.print("Im Text file")};
}

public class VideoProcess implements FileProcess{ 
   public void process(){System.out.print("Im Video file")};
}

public class AudioProcess implements FileProcess{ 
   public void process(){System.out.print("Im Audio file")};
}
```

I run test that get File from post request (for example a.jpg or 12.txt or aaa.pdf) how can I know what file process to run?
in other words how can I know which object process should be created?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear , and how does this linked to polymorphism . just because your implementing the interface ?

Comment: What is it that you want here?

Comment: header will tell you the type of file which you can use as switch case to create appropriate object using a static factory

Answer (score 5):

First note your methods are not correct, a `"` is missing:

```
public class VideoProcess implements FileProcess{ 
   public void process(){System.out.print("Im Video file")};
   //                                                   ^ here!
}
```

Either you don't have `ImageProcess` object...

---

This is a classic [Factory Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) . To achieve the correct behaviour, in this case, you can create a generic object and check the extension to create concrete instances:

```
FileProcess process = null;
String filename = "a.jpg";
String extension = filename(0, filename(lastIndexOf(".");
```

And use it to choose what kind of object create:

```
switch(extension) {
    // catch multiple image extensions:
    case "jpg":
    case "png":
        process = new VideoProcess();
        break;

    // catch text
    case "txt":
        process = new TextProcess();
        break;

    // catch multiple audio extensions:
    case "wav":
    case "mp3":
        process = new AudioProcess();
        break;

}
```

Also I would highly reccomend to use a `Factory` class as described in the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) (**STEP 3**) that returns the correct object.

Comment: nice to hear, if doubts following link or answer provided let me know, link explains really nice how to create a simple and great factory pattern easily that will make your code rock ;)